# Avoid updating a same value in MYSQL and displaying the error in the client side

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, sql-update

I have come across many questions and answers related to this kind of questions, but not for exactly this question.

Well, according to the official [MYSQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) it says

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this
>   and does not update it.

But practically, when I update a same value to a MYSQL column, the query successfully executing and displaying "*Your query has been successfully executed "*.

So How do I exactly know that the query hasn't updated, when I update a column with the same value?

Also Is it possible to get an error message to the client (browser), when I try to update a same value, from the browser via a *submit form* to the MYSQL server via a backend language like PHP?

Comment: MySQL also returns rows affected which PHPs MySQLi and PDO have a way of reading so you can use that to check whether the number of rows updated is the number you needed to update. However you can't know which ones did not update unless you have read them beforehand.

Comment: maybe this would help: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: In addition to what @MubasharIqbal noted, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php for PDO

Comment: "Your query has been successfully executed" is not the same as "found rows to update". It just means that your query didn't fail.

Answer (score 2):

When updating a Mysql table with identical values nothing's really affected so rowCount will return 0.

Just create your PDO object with

```
<?php
$p = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS => true));
?>
```

and `rowCount()` will tell you how many rows your update-query actually found/matched.

Check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) also.

Answer (score -2):

you may use like to avoid updating same value
    UPDATE users
    SET    first_name = 'Michael'
    WHERE  id = 123
    AND   first_name IS DISTINCT FROM 'Michael';

Comment: I can't execute this as MSQL says **unrecognized keyword near DISTINCT**

Comment: This isn't a valid SQL query. Even if it was, it would still give the OP the same result as before. `DISTINCT` goes in the `SELECT` part. You can't just shove in SQL keywords where ever you like. Please read [the manual about distinct](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)